# Can debugging symbols be built after-the-fact?

Tags: debugging, windbg, symbols

We have hundreds of MSVC 9.0 C++ projects. One DLL slipped out into the public without the correct compiler/linker settings to generate symbols, and we are getting mini-dumps back that point to an exception in this DLL. We have the exact source code used to generate this DLL. Can it be compiled to produce symbols that we can use to debug these dumps? If so, how do I tell windbg "please use these symbols for this DLL even though the timestamps will be different"? Thanks.

Comment: Thumbs up that you atleast have some supporting processes so that you can determine the code using which your Dll was built.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the   `.reload /i` command to load mismatch symbols.

> /i ignores a mismatch in the .pdb file
>   versions. (If you do not include this
>   parameter, the debugger does not load
>   mismatched symbol files.) When you use
>   /i, /f is used also, even if you do
>   not explicitly specify it.

HTH